# How can I, using Perl, filter out IP addresses from a log file or any other file?

Tags: perl, unix, solaris

I am trying to find out how I can use Perl to scan thru a specific file and find all the IP addresses and block them so that I can convert the numbers in the IP address to x's. For example: 194.66.82.11 and after the code runs it is formatted like `xxx.xx.xx.11` instead of just removing it completely. This is in unix.

Comment: Do you also need to consider IPv6?

Comment: nope, just IPv4 @knittl

Comment: put some part of your log

Comment: You can use RegEx to do it.

Comment: @ashish 

192.168.72.177 - - [22/Dec/2002:23:32:19 -0400] "GET 
   /search.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1997 www.yahoo.com 
   "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ...)" "-"

Answer (score 0):

You've stated in the comments that you're working with a log file:

```
192.168.72.177 - - [22/Dec/2002:23:32:19 -0400] "GET /search.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1997 www.yahoo.com "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ...)" "-" –
```

I therefore suggest that you just edit the first field of the log file to achieve your result.

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -lane '$F[0] =~ s/\d(?=.*\.)/x/g; print "@F"' file.log
```

Outputs:

```
xxx.xxx.xx.177 - - [22/Dec/2002:23:32:19 -0400] "GET /search.php HTTP/1.1" 400 1997 www.yahoo.com "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ...)" "-" –
```

Answer (score -1):

To match 4 numbers (with a maximum length of 3) separated with a period you can use the following regex:

```
(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})
```

You can access the last capturing group (the first is a non-capturing group) with `\1` when replacing, thus `xxx.xxx.xxx.\1`, for instance. Note that the result will not have the same number of `x`s as the original IP had digits. If that's a problem you'd have to tweak the regex.

Comment: like this? 

perl -nle (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}([0-9]{1,3});' filename